# Splitting sentence string into array of words, then array of words into arrays of characters within the array of words

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working through a problem on freecodecamp.com, and I want to see whether my code so far is doing what I think it is doing...

```
function titleCase(str) {
  var wordArr = str.split(' '); // now the sentences is an array of words
  for (var i = 0; i < wordArr.length; i++) { //looping through the words now...
    charArr = wordArr[i].split(''); //charArr is a 2D array of characters within words?
    return charArr[1][1];
  }

}

titleCase("a little tea pot"); // this should give me 'i', right?
```

Again, this is just the beginning of the code. My goal is to capitalize the first letter of each word in the parameter of `titleCase();`. Perhaps I'm not even going about this right at all.

But... is `charArr` on line 4 a multidimensional array. Did that create `[['a'],['l','i','t','t','l','e'],['t','e','a','p','o','t']]`?

Comment: Your `return` statement will prevent your loop from running more than once. Also you need to indicate what your code is actually doing if not what you described. Maybe check out [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to ABR answer (I can't comment yet) :

charArr is a one-dimensional array, if you want it to be a 2d array you need to push the result of wordArr[i].split(''); instead of assigning it.

```
charArr.push(wordArr[i].split(''));
```

And don't forget to initialize charArr as an empty array

Comment: Ah... Yes! I was pretty sure this was what I was looking for, but I had trouble  resolving it in my head and getting it into the code the right way. Should have struggled on a bit longer and worked it out. Thanks so much to you and to @ABR!

Answer (score 1):

Few issues :
1. Your return statement will stop this after one iteration.
2. If one of the words have fewer then 2 letters (like the first one in your example, which is 'a') - you will get an exception at charArr[1][1].

Other then that, it is mostly ok.
It would probably help you to download a tool like firebug and test your code live...

Comment: You forgot to mention that `charArr` is a one-dimensional array of characters, so referencing `charArr[1][1]` is a bit silly.

Comment: Thanks! I should definitely get a tool like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
function titleCase(str) {
    var newString = "";
    var wordArr = str.split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < wordArr.length; i++) { //looping through the words now...
        var firstLetter = wordArr[i].slice(0,1); // get the first letter
        //capitalize the first letter and attach the rest of the word
        newString += firstLetter.toUpperCase() + wordArr[i].substring(1) + " ";
    } 
 return newString;
}
```

Also you need to remove the `return statement` in your `for loop` because the first time the for loop goes over the `return` statement, it will end the function and you will not be able to loop through all the words

---

Here you can learn more about `string.slice()` : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp

Comment: Thanks! That looks really good. Had not yet familiarized myself with `.slice()`.

Comment: Here you can learn more `string.slice()` : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp

Comment: Hey ckperez, you need to close this question by accepting 1 of the answers. You can click the check mark beside an answer to do so.